# Function Javascript - validando si es Vocal

Tags: javascript, funciones, validación

Sigo con mi tarea y me encontré con el siguiente problema en mi código:

```
function esVocal(letra){
  //Escribe una función que reciba una letra y, si es una vocal, muestre el mensaje “Es vocal”. 
  //Verificar si el usuario ingresó un string de más de un carácter, en ese caso, informarle 
  //que no se puede procesar el dato mediante el mensaje "Dato incorrecto".
  // Si no es vocal, tambien debe devolver "Dato incorrecto".
  //Escribe tu código aquí
  if (letra == "A" || "E" || "I" || "O" || "U" || "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" ||"u") {
    return " Es vocal"
  }
  if (letra != "A" || "E" || "I" || "O" || "U" || "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u") {
    return " Dato incorrecto"
  }
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despues de cada || tienes que volver a poner la condición es decir la comparación entre la variable y el string `letra == "A" || letra == "E"`

**Ejemplo**

```
if (letra == "A" || letra == "E" || letra == "I" || letra == "O" || letra == "U" || letra == "a" || letra == "e" || letra == "i" || letra == "o" || letra == "u") {
    return " Es vocal"
}else{
    return " Dato incorrecto"
}
```

Comment: Gracias! al final tuve que hacerlo con === pero en cada letra como me lo dijiste!

Comment: Si tu pregunta ha sido resuelta por favor marca como buena la respuesta gracias.

Comment: Esta es *la respuesta correcta para la pregunta del usuario*. `letra` debe compararse con cada carácter. Lo que hace @Skywire-cl es precisamente no hacerlo de esta manera. Sin embargo, como código es más funcional y esta mejor planteado el ejemplo de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/519599/20709
Si un elemento ha de compararse con un grupo de otros elementos, incluir estos en un array y usar `includes` simplifica notablemente el código, p.e. comprobar si un número forma parte de una serie de números:
`const number = 1; const arrNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5]; console.log(arrNumbers.includes(number));`

Comment: @Orici Estoy completamente de acuerdo, no quería simplificarlo mucho debido a que en alguna otras preguntas me han pedido cosas mas simples :)

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya tienes una respuesta al problema, publico esta otra que ataca la solución de una forma diferente.

Una de las razones de hacerlo como lo voy a mostrar es para mejorar un poco la cantidad de comparaciones que debes hacer. Veo innecesario escribir tantas comparaciones.

Puedes lograr el mismo resultado sólo con un `Array` que contenga las vocales en mayúscula (o en minúscula).

Por ejemplo:

```js
function esVocal(letra) {
  //Escribe una función que reciba una letra y, si es una vocal, muestre el mensaje “Es vocal”. 
  //Verificar si el usuario ingresó un string de más de un carácter, en ese caso, informarle 
  //que no se puede procesar el dato mediante el mensaje "Dato incorrecto".
  // Si no es vocal, tambien debe devolver "Dato incorrecto".
  //Escribe tu código aquí
  if(letra.length !== 1) {
    return "Dato incorrecto";
  }
  const vocales = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  if(vocales.includes(letra.toLowerCase())) {
    return "Es vocal";
  }
  return "Dato incorrecto";
}

console.log(esVocal('B'));
console.log(esVocal('ab'));
console.log(esVocal('E'));
console.log(esVocal('u'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

una forma simple que podes resolverlo, es de la siguiente manera:

```
    if (letra.length !== 1) {
    return "Dato incorrecto"
  }
  else if (letra === "a" || letra ==="e" || letra ==="i" ||
  letra === "o" || letra === "u") {
    return "Es vocal";
  }
  else if(letra !== "a" || letra !=="e" || letra !=="i" ||
  letra !== "o" || letra !== "u") {
    return "Dato incorrecto";
  }
```

te conviene primero que nada verificar si ingresó mas de una letra, así en ese caso directamente salís de la función sin perder tiempo en comparar

Answer (score 0):

```js
function esVocal( letra ) {
    const totalLetra = ["a","e","i","o","u"].some((item => item == letra))
    return totalLetra ? "Es vocal" : "Dato incorrecto"
}

let array = [ "a", "e", "b", "c", "ce", "u" ];

for( let i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    console.log( esVocal( array[ i ] ))
}
```

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques mínimamente como funciona, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y/o que la misma sea cerrada.