# se podrea minificar esto

Tags: javascript

```js
function vocal(letra) { 
  letra === "a" || letra === "e" || letra === "i" || letra === "o" || letra === "u" ?   console.log("es vocal") :  console.log("es consonante")
}
vocal("b")
```

mejorar el codigo ? para hacerlo mas legible o mas pequeño

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. Las preguntas acerca de optimización de código "van mejor" en [codereview.se] (en inglés).

Comment: Responde esto tu pregunta? [Function Javascript - validando si es Vocal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519540/function-javascript-validando-si-es-vocal)

Comment: Honestamente, a mi gusto, agregar un if en lugar de un ternario y poner cada clausula en una linea lo hace mucho mas legible....

Comment: ¿Y si le pones A?

Answer (score 1):

Esto que buscas es posible hacerlo gracias al método match con una expresión regular:

```js
const tieneVocal = e => {
  return e.match(/[aeiou]/) ? console.log('Es vocal') : console.log('Es consonante')
}

tieneVocal('e')
```

Podrías añadir más letras y te dirá si hay alguna vocal en todas ellas.

Comment: Usar expresiones regulares para esto es como matar zancudos a cañonazos.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando expresiones regulares y arrow function se simplificaría.

`let vocal = letra => letra === /[aeiou]/i ? console.log("es vocal") : console.log("es consonante");`

`vocal(2);`

Comment: gracias buen hombre esta interesante

Comment: Usar expresiones regulares para esto es como matar zancudos a cañonazos.